# ERROR: call to a member function get() on null

Tags: php, error-handling, opencart

I got this error message:

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function get() on null in /home/key2demo/domains/key2datafeed.com/public_html/ocdemoshops/oc23/system/engine/controller.php on line 10

All the code in the controller is:

```
<?php
abstract class Controller {
    protected $registry;

    public function __construct($registry) {
        $this->registry = $registry;
    }

    public function __get($key) {
        return $this->registry->get($key);
    }

    public function __set($key, $value) {
        $this->registry->set($key, $value);
    }
}
```

The code i use registry in is this:

```
define("VERSION", "1.0");
define("LANGUAGE", "1");

if (is_file('./../admin/config.php')) {
   require_once('./../admin/config.php');
}

require_once(DIR_SYSTEM . 'startup.php');

$application_config = 'admin';
$registry = new Registry();

$loader = new Loader($registry);
$registry->set('load', $loader);

$config = new Config();
$config->load('default');

$config->load($application_config);
$registry->set('config', $config);
$registry->set('request', new Request());
$response = new Response();

$response->addHeader('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$registry->set('response', $response);

$registry->set('cache', new Cache($config->get('cache_type'), $config-
>get('cache_expire')));
$registry->set('url', new Url($config->get('site_ssl')));

$language = new Language($config->get('language_default'));
$language->load($config->get('language_default'));

$registry->set('language', $language);
$registry->set('document', new Document());

$event = new Event($registry);
$registry->set('event', $event);

if ($config->get('db_autostart')) {
   $registry->set('db', new DB($config->get('db_type'), $config-
   >get('db_hostname'), $config->get('db_username'), $config-
   >get('db_password'), $config->get('db_database'), $config-
   >get('db_port')));
}

if ($config->get('session_autostart')) {
   $session = new Session();
   $session->start();
   $registry->set('session', $session);
}

if ($config->has('action_event')) {
   foreach ($config->get('action_event') as $key => $value) {
      $event->register($key, new Action($value));
   }
}

if ($config->has('config_autoload')) {
   foreach ($config->get('config_autoload') as $value) {
     $loader->config($value);
   }
}

if ($config->has('language_autoload')) {
   foreach ($config->get('language_autoload') as $value) {
      $loader->language($value);
    }
}

if ($config->has('library_autoload')) {
   foreach ($config->get('library_autoload') as $value) {
      $loader->library($value);
   }
}

if ($config->has('model_autoload')) {
   foreach ($config->get('model_autoload') as $value) {
      $loader->model($value);
   }
}

class K2P_API_OCWRITER extends Controller
{ 

   private $errors;
private $admin;
private $adminValidated;
private $adminShops;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->errors = array();
}

public function doLog($message)
{
    file_put_contents('./key2_log.txt', $message, FILE_APPEND);
}

public function login($usr, $pwd)
{   

    if ($this->user->login($usr, $pwd)) {
        return true;
        $this->doLog('logged in');
    } else {
        $this->doLog('Failed to login, please supply a valid 
         username/password and check your webshop url');
        die;
    }

}

public function getLanguages()
{
}

}

$db = new DB(DB_DRIVER, DB_HOSTNAME, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);
$registry->set('db', $db);
$registry->set('user', new Cart\User($registry));
$registry->set('tax', new Cart\Tax($registry));

$myAPI = new K2P_API_OCWRITER($registry);
$myAPI->config->set("config_language_id",LANGUAGE);
$command = $myAPI->cleanPost($_POST['command']);
$steps = $myAPI->cleanPost($_POST['steps']);
$page = $myAPI->cleanPost($_POST['page']);
$usr = $myAPI->cleanPost($_POST['usr']);
$pwd = $myAPI->cleanPost($_POST['pwd']);
//$myAPI->doLog(PHP_EOL . 'pages: ' . $page);
//$myAPI->doLog(PHP_EOL . 'steps: ' . $steps);
$totalProducts = $myAPI->getProductCount();
if ($myAPI->checkInput($usr,$pwd,$command,$page,$steps)) {
   if ($myAPI->login($usr, $pwd)) {
       switch($command){
          case "getCategoryCount":
              echo json_encode($myAPI->getCategoryCount(),JSON_FORCE_OBJECT 
              | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
            break;
        case "getProductCount";
            echo json_encode($myAPI->getProductCount(),JSON_FORCE_OBJECT | 
            JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
            break;
        case "getCategories":
            echo json_encode($myAPI->getCategories($steps, $page, 
            JSON_FORCE_OBJECT | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES));
            break;
        case "getProducts":
            echo json_encode($myAPI->getProducts($steps, $page, 
            JSON_FORCE_OBJECT | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES));
            break;
        default:
            echo "Invalid command!";
            break;
    }
 }
}
```

How can i fix it?

Comment: Check value of `$registry`.

Comment: I updated my question. I added the code on the page I use the $registry. Can you see what is going wrong. And do you know how to fix it?

Comment: `constructor` in child class overwrites the one in parent. So parent constructor does not run and does not set `this->registry`

Comment: How can i fix it? Can i put the code of the public function __construct($registry) {
        $this->registry = $registry;
    }
in the public function __construct()
{
    $this->errors = array();
}?

Comment: Use `parent::__construct`

Comment: So, just for sure, it has to be like this: public function __construct($registry) { 
                parent::__construct();
  $this->registry = $registry;
 }

Comment: if i do it the way i did in the last comment i get the error: [Wed Apr 19 11:38:43.622931 2017] [:error] [pid 25517] [client 217.21.198.78:62933] PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on null in /home/key2demo/domains/key2datafeed.com/public_html/ocdemoshops/oc23/system/engi‌​ne/controller.php on line 11

Answer (score 1):

The error not in the abstract class. It's where you actually invoked the a property directly by calling $var->property1 since it's obviously the __get() magic method that's producing the error, which invokes the class get() method. Your controller's registry object needs to have the get() method. You probably don't have the correct registry obj passed into the controller constructor.

Comment: I updated my question. I added the code on the page I use the $registry. Can you see what is going wrong. And do you know how to fix it?

Comment: Let's see your registry class.